# Having problem with icon file path in python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, filepath

Suppose my py file and icons folders are inside 'Project Folder'. Inside the 'icons' folder, there is another folder, the name is 'png'. 'bold-button.png' is inside that 'png' folder.

Now below code is on line number 110:

```
bold_icon = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'icons/png/bold-button.png')
```

if I run this code, the terminal shows me the below error.
[image: Error Message]

What to do, and how to solve it? I have tried a lot, and the path is ok...but it still shows up with this error. even I have tried to open that file with open() but still shows me that path error. what's wrong with my path?

Comment: Could you please format the error message a bit, just saying, it's kinda hard to read
Maybe add a screenshot of the error message or somethin
PS: thnx :)

Comment: According to the traceback, you did not specify the file extension in the icon path: `bold_icon = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'icons/png/bold-button')`.

Comment: @NovusEdge Okey, I have added the photo. Take a look at that. If I use the full path then it is working but if I use a relative path then it is not working.

Comment: @acw1668 I forgot, but now take a look at the Image I have added. One more thing,  If I use the full path then it is working but if I use a relative path then it is not working.

Comment: Your current directory is `D:\Python` but the image is `D:\Python\Taditor\icons\png\bold-button.png`.  However, relative path `icons\png\bold-button.png` is referring `D:\Python\icons\png\bold-button.png`.  You should change the directory to `D:\Python\Taditor` and execute the python script.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks, it worked and I have learned something new. How can I upvote or 'accepted' your answer? I am not seeing any option here.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the current directory `D:\Python` is not the same as the directory (`D:\Python\Taditor`) where your python script is.  So the relative path `icons\png\bold-button.png` is referring to `D:\Python\icons\png\bold-button.png`, but not the expected `D:\Python\Taditor\icons\png\bold-button.png`.

Just change the current directory to `D:\Python\Taditor` and execute your python script there.